# clear session data after multi-page form submit in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I've a 4-page form, where in 3rd form i'm selecting an image for upload. I'm storing the contents of first 3 forms in session. after 4th form is submitted, i'm collecting the required data from session variables and saving them in database. 
How do i destroy the session variables in django after 4th form is submitted because when i'm filling a new 4-page form, i get the previously uploaded image in 3rd form.

Is there any better way to execute multi-page forms in django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `del request.session['key']` to delete data from session. So try like this:

```
def fourth_form_submission(request):
    form = FourthForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        # save data to DB from session
        try:
            del request.session['form_1_data']
            del request.session['form_2_data']
            del request.session['form_3_data']
        except KeyError:
            pass
       return HttpResponse("Data has been saved.")
```

Or you can use [**`flush()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush), but it will delete all session data.

More information can be found regarding this in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved).